# Como adicionar duas li em uma ul dinamicamente com jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, append

html:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  Adicionar aqui
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Preciso adicionar duas li onde está escrito: "Adicionar aqui". Alguém sabe como fazer isso usando jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método "after" do jQuery. Exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $li = $('ul li').eq(1);
  
  $('button').click(function() {
    $li.after('<li>' + $('ul li').length + '</li>');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<button>Adicionar</button>
```

Comment: Funcionou como esperado. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o pseudo seletor [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) uma vez que você saiba a partir de qual "filho" você deseja inserir conteúdo.

```js
$('ul > li:nth-child(2)').after(`
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
`)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Aí vc está inserindo dentro da segunda <li> e não após.

Comment: Sim, esta errado o correto seria `.after()`